# Understanding Return, Enter, and stty icrlf

Tags: terminal, stty

In Ubuntu/gnome-terminal, if I run:

```
$ stty -icrnl
```

Then launch the GHC interactive environment (a Haskell console):

```
$ ghci
```

Then pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> does not submit the line; however, <kbd>Enter</kbd> does.

However, with:

```
$ stty icrnl
```

Both <kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> submit the line.

I don't really understand the behaviour; surely <kbd>Return</kbd> will be submitting the newline character in both cases?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first step in understanding what's going on is to be aware that there are in fact two “newline” characters. There's [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) (CR, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) and [line feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (LF, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>). On a [teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Corporation), CR moves the printer head to the beginning of the line while LF moves the paper down by one line. For user input, there's only one relevant concept, which is “the user has finished entering a line”, but unfortunately there's been some divergence: Unix systems, as well as the very popular C language, use line feed to represent line breaks; but terminals send a carriage return when the user presses the <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

The `icrnl` setting tells the terminal driver in the kernel to convert the CR character to LF on input. This way, applications only need to worry about one newline character; the same newline character that ends lines in files also ends lines of user input on the terminal, so the application doesn't need to have a special case for that.

By default, ghci, or rather the [haskeline](http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline/wiki/KeyBindings) library that it uses, has a key binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, i.e. LF, to stop accumulating input and start processing it. It has no binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> i.e. CR. So if the terminal isn't converting CR to LF, ghci doesn't know what to do with that character.

Haskeline instructs the terminal to report keypad keys with escape sequences. It queries the terminal's [terminfo settings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) to know what those escape sequences are (`kent` entry in the terminfo database). (The terminfo database is also how it knows how to enable keypad escapes: it sends the `smkx` escape sequence, and it sends `rmkx` on exit to restore the default keypad character mode.) When you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the keypad in ghci, that sends the escape sequence `\eOM`, which haskeline recognizes as a binding to stop accumulating input and start processing it.

Comment: Experimenting with this just now I found that the behavior of `Return` and `Enter` always sends 0x0a (LF). But depending on the settings for `icrnl` or `inlcr` you many influence the mapping for `Ctrl-J` and `Ctrl-M`. Is there a way to change the behavior of the `Return` and `Enter` keys?

Comment: @sherrellbc It depends on your terminal emulator.

Answer (score 6):

Referring to both <kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> sounds as if you are describing the keys respectively on the *main* part of the keyboard and on the numeric keypad often on the right-side of the main part:

[image]

However, only the *first* of those corresponds to the key which (unmodified) sends <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.  The key on the numeric keypad *may* send a carriage return or whatever, but may actually send an escape sequence, e.g., <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, for VT100-like terminals.

You can see the different key values by echoing them, e.g., using `cat -v`.

Comment: I find that `xterm` sends `\eOM` only after a `tput smkx` and without num-lock. I'd doubt a tty line discipline would treat `\eOM` (and not `\r`) as accept-line though, so I'd find it unlikely to explain the behaviour shown by the OP

Comment: OP is referring to behavior within `ghci`, which could modify the keypad-setting.

Comment: Indeed, ghci does seem to have its own line editor that honours `\eOM` as accept-line. It does change the line discipline (to leave icanon at least), but does not touch `icrnl`. So it does explain the OP's problem indeed.