# Why in the output of script (1) the newline is CR + LF (dos-style)?

Tags: tty, console, newlines, typescript

In the typescript of `script` command (i.e. in the saved file), the newline is CR + LF (\r\n), although the original one (fed to `script`) is LF. Why?
It seems it's tty issue, which I don't know at all. Can someone explain it without much detail?

I'm not in any trouble; I'm just curious. :) (But I think it's better to fix it, or at leasd should be documented.)

My `script` is from util-linux, but probably it does not matter much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My own answer, after learning from [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343325/190880) and the comment by [icarus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/194382/icarus):
You have to distinguish "a newline in a file" and "a newline in a console". In a console, the true newline is, counter-intuitively, CRLF, as we will see below.

In UNIX convetion, in text files LF means a newline, and vice versa, you mean a newline by LF. (By "you mean", I mean say in a natural language text.) In DOS CR+LF, and so on. Ok. Everyone knows it.

(Unix) console are more complicated. First you have to remember LF and CR are control codes, i.e. can be used to *control* a console, e.g. getting bold, color, etc.

If you feed a LF (\n, linefeed) to a console, then you get a newline. The catch is, well, the *two* catches are: (1) Consoles are double layered, so to say; they consist of a filter and a rendering part. (Ad hoc nomenclature.) The hidden (to ordinary users) filter translates LF to CRLF. (2) The renderer needs CRLF(\r\n) for a newline in ordinary sense. See below for more.

The typescript file created by the `script (1)` command records the characters *after* the input to the console is filtered. That's why newlines in typescript is CRLF.

Details & misc. facts:

- The console renderer prints LF as "move down cursor one line" and CR as "move the cursor to the beginning of the line."
- You can turn off LF->CRLF conversion by `$ stty -opost` and efface it by `$ stty opost`. "opost" is an abbreviation of "Output POSTprocessing".

  - More precisely, `opost` does LF->LFCR when  `onlcr` is set. When `onocr` is set, CR will be deleted when at the beginnig of line, etc. Ref: POSIX chap 11 "[General Terminal Interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html)".
- To "Enter" key is bound to LF in Unix, called "Return" in keymap terminology. (See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253271/understanding-return-enter-and-stty-icrlf) for the details.)
- There's also escape code variants; `man 4 console_codes` explains that "ESC D" (\eD) is linefeed, and "ESC E" (\eE) is newline. If you print them, "ESC D" is a "move cursor down", and "ESC E" a CR+LF, regardless of ±opost-ness.

To do some experiments, I recommend to write from a separate console. For example `$ echo -ne '1st\n2nd\r\n3rd\n" > /dev/tty1` writes to the first non-X console, and `/dev/pts/0` is the first X terminal. This is not the most convenient way, but least ambiguous.

Answer (score 7):

The deep reason for the discrepancy between program output and a captured tty stream (e.g. `typescript`) is that tty's used to be *printers*.

Before unix, text always had a CRLF at the end of a line, not because it was considered to be the logical representation of a line termination, but because the characters individually had real physical meaning: move the print head all the way to the left, and advance the paper.

Unix took a radical new approach: it treats text files on disk as a useful object in their own right (not just instructions for a printer), and lines as logical entities. The two-character line terminator is unnecessarily complicated in the unix worldview.

But they had to work with existing hardware - printers and CRT dumb terminals that didn't recognize a single "end of line" character, but only a CR to do half the job and an LF to do the other half. So a translation had to be done, and it was done at the closest possible place to that hardware - in the tty driver.

Since then, it's all been backward compatibility. So you have a terminal emulator that insists on CRLF, and a tty driver that supplies it when a program outputs a newline.

Comment: TTYs never really stopped being printers.  You are using TTY, _teletypewriter_, to mean _terminal_,  It's a common conflation in Unix Land, but especially in discussions that lean on the history of computing there _is_ a distinction.

Comment: I don't think it's bad to refer to the devices represented by `/dev/tty*` as "tty's". It doesn't just stand for "teletype(writer)" any more. It evolved a new meaning. Language does that.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a history of newline, not having a direct relation to the question. The last paragraph is meaningless, since it's simply tantamount to saying "if it's the case, it is the case."

Comment: The history *is* the reason. `script` doesn't exist in a vacuum.

Answer (score 6):

The `typescript` output captures all the characters sent to the pty. If you use for example `stty -opost` to stop the terminal driver from doing its normal change of the newline character to CR+LF then you will see that you only have LF characters in the output.

Hopefully helpful tip, use

```
col -b < typescript
```

to do a first pass at cleaning up the file.

Comment: Let us be precise. (1) In the original console (I tried linux console and X terms) the newline is LF. (2) In the console that `script` seems to set up, or more precisely `$ script -c <command>` where `command` can be dash, bash, or any program, the newline is CR+LF. So by `stty -opost` it can be changed to LF. (3) A typescript file is a faithful copy of the console that `script` makes.

Comment: Am I right? If so why the item (2)? Is it an idiosyncrasy of `script`, or Linux (perhaps Unix in general) default? The git repo of `script.c` from util-linux is found at: [(raw)](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/plain/term-utils/script.c), [(tree)](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/term-utils/script.c)

Comment: @teikakazura (3) is correct, (1) is wrong, not sure what to say about (2). In a **file** the newline is LF. The driver for the consoles usually translates this LF to CRLF, but other options are possible. The `stty -opost` turns off all output translations. Try running `stty -opost; head /etc/passwd ; stty opost; head /etc/passwd` to see that a LF just moves you down a line and you need the the translation.

Comment: Do you know how the terminal escapes can be filtered?  `col -b` doesn't take care of those.  Edit: Just found it; https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684/135943