# Enter key is different from Carriage Return (CR)

Tags: terminal, vim, newlines, special-characters

Many webpages said that ASCII code for enter key is 13(0d).
Enter key is considered as Carriage Return (CR).
Now let's make an experiment.
To open vim and just click enter key for three times ,do nothing more,then save the file as test.csv.

```
xxd  test.csv
0000000: 0a0a 0a
```

My conclusions got.
The enter key's ascii value is 0a ,meaning newline ,it is different from Carriage Return (13 or 0d in ascii).
Is right or not?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253271/5132 .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your terminal sends carriage return when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and on Unix-like systems, the terminal **driver** translates that into line-feed ("newline").

That's the `icrnl` feature shown by `stty -a`, e.g.,

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Programs (even shell scripts) can turn that off to read the actual carriage return character to distinguish it from <kbd>*Control*</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> (line feed).

Comment: Yes but that's irrelevant. In Vim, `icrnl` is off.

Comment: Try reading the last sentence again, to see if you understand it.

Comment: The fact that “programs can” in the last sentence can be instantiated with “Vim does” to make a true sentence implies that everything that you explained previously is irrelevant. Which leaves your post not answering the question at all.

Answer (score 8):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key does send a CR character (carriage return, Ctrl+M, numerical value 13 = 0x0d = 015). You can see that at a shell prompt or in Vi insert mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is a keyboard shortcut to enter the next character literally in the kernel's built-in terminal driver as well as in many terminal-based programs including typical shell and Vi(m).

In Vi(m) insert mode, the character Ctrl+M is bound to the command “insert line break”. Vi reacts to most input characters by inserting that characters, but there are a few exceptions, most obviously the character Ctrl+[ which is what the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key sends.

In a text file, a line break is represented by a LF character (line feed, Ctrl+J, numerical value 10 = 0x0a = 013).

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in Vi would actually have the same effect, but you could bind the two keystrokes to separate commands if you wanted. You can observe a difference between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> in command mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> simply moves the cursor down to the next line whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> moves the cursor down to the next line and also moves it to the first non-blank character.