# Why do ^M and \r behave inconsistently?

Tags: terminal, history, terminal-emulator, ascii, control-characters

Perhaps there are already answers out there that indirectly answer my question, but I've read many of them and haven't yet found a satisfactory answer to this discrepancy.

The original meaning of carriage return comes from old teleprinters: it meant to move the print head to the left in the current line. If you kept writing in the current line, you would be overwriting what was already written. Nowadays, we can specify this behaviour with the text symbol `\r`, which is typed explicitly within a string. For example, in Python you can do `print('hello\rgoodbye')`, and in the terminal you can do `echo $'hello\rgoodbye'`, and in both cases you will only see `goodbye`.

In contrast, a pseudo-carriage return can also be inserted interactively with the ASCII control character `^M` (typed with `Ctrl-M` or with `Enter`). I call it pseudo-carriage return because even though it is widely called carriage return, surprisingly it doesn't insert `\r`, but rather it inserts `\n`, which is the symbol for a new line.

So interactively typing `hello`, then `Ctrl-M`, then `goodbye`, surprisingly doesn't achieve the equivalent of `hello\rgoodbye`, but rather the equivalent of `hello\ngoodbye`.

Isn't this very inconsistent? What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: By chance [this fresh answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1648043/432690) can advance your research, I believe.

Comment: I've used Model 33, Model 35, and Model 35ASR TeleTypes. Control-M, "\r", Carriage Return returned the print head to the left margin. Control-J, "\n", Linefeed advanced the paper 1 line. Unix/Linux decided on Control-J for End-of-line. Some programs convert `\r` for you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the result of the terminal’s input handling: by default, the terminal device driver (software in the kernel of your operating system to handle input from the terminal, not the terminal itself) converts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. You can see this by running

```
od -t x1
```

and then entering both characters:

```
$ od -t x1
^M
^J
^D
0000000 0a 0a
0000002
```

(You won’t see `^M` etc. on screen.)

Thus when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, whatever program is processing your input doesn’t see a carriage return, it sees a line feed instead.

This can be configured with `stty icrnl`. See [Understanding Return, Enter, and stty icrlf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253271/86440) for a similar question.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. If I understood correctly, there was some divergence such that many Unix programs and the C language started to use line feed `^J` or `\n`, whereas terminals went their own way and started to interpret `Enter` as carriage return `^M` or `\r`. At some point, Unix and C became very widespread, so terminals had to somehow revert back to be more compatible with Unix and C. The easiest way to do this was to add the layer of interpretation of `stty icrnl`, and convert `^M` to `^J`. Is this a roughly correct account of the historical development?

Comment: I’m not sure when `icrnl` was added to termio or termios, but Unix always had a separation between its internal expectations and how terminals worked (inherited from Multics); I’m not sure things diverged as such, terminals were already varied when Unix was created. [This related answer I wrote on Retro.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6384/79) goes into some of the history and provides pointers to more detailed explanations.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, because it seems about the opposite of the way things work on Windows.  There the Enter key is converted to \r\n, and the C runtime library will convert that back to \n if you open a file in "text" mode.